# EXCEL VBA: trying to write a table in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, vba, ado

I´m trying to write a table into a MySQL Database, ich searched for many Examples but id didn´t working and i hav no idea why.

my Code:

```
    Private Sub abfrage()

Dim xlsstring As String
Dim xlsrecordsetarray
Dim xlsadodbconnection As New ADODB.Connection
Dim xlsrecordset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim xlssource As String
Dim xlsconnect As String

Dim sqlstring As String
Dim sqlrecordsetarray
Dim sqladodbconnection As New ADODB.Connection
Dim sqlrecordset As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlsource As String
Dim sqlconnect As String

xlssource = ThisWorkbook.FullName
'xlssource ="C:\mappe1.xls"

'SQL Verbindung für Exceldatei als Quelle
xlsconnect = "PROVIDER=MSDASQL.1;" & _
            "DSN=Excel Files;" & _
            "DBQ=" & xlssource & ";" & _
            "HDR=Yes;"


sqlconnect = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver};" & _
            "DATA SOURCE=MySQL ODBC;" & _
            "SERVER=localhost;" & _
            "PORT=3306;" & _
            "UID=root;" & _
            "PWD=root;" & _
            "DATABASE=test;"

xlsadodbconnection.Open xlsconnect
sqladodbconnection.Open sqlconnect

sqlstring = "INSERT INTO test (ID, text) SELECT id, text FROM [Tabelle1$]"
sqlrecordset.Open sqlstring, sqladodbconnection

xlsrecordset.Close
xlsadodbconnection.Close
sqladodbconnection.Close

End Sub
```

it shows me the error:

[MySQL[ODBC 5.3(w) Driver][mysqld-5.6.16]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[Tabelle1$]' at Line 1

please, can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the name of the table [Tabelle1$] in MySQL? Are you adding the "[" and "]" vba-style?

If so, try removing those and running your query again.

**edited per comments:**

Save your spreadsheet as a .CSV and try using the "LOAD DATA INFILE LOCAL" command to move the data into a temp table on your MySQL server.

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_26714181.html

Comment: it´s exactly like in my post, [Tabelle1$] is the excel sheet that i want to insert into sql table "test"

Comment: The MySQL server is throwing an error because it doesn't "see" the Excel spreadsheet on your local machine. My approach would be to write a loop that reads the data and runs the INSERT query for each row in Excel. Or to import the excel file into a temp table and then run your query against that table.

Comment: and how can i solve this?
yeah i see the first solution very often but i don´t like it very much.
your second solution sounds interesting, can you give me one example please?

Comment: Try following this [link] (http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?32,216343,216344#msg-216344)  Essentially you will import the file as a csv into a temp table, then massage the data into your table using an INSERT query like the one you have above.

Comment: For performance I often find myself loading large imports this way. I create a temp table using the HEAP storage engine and drop the table when I'm finished loading the data.